# [iOS Swift4]How to back ViewControllers (modal and push)

Tags: ios, swift

[Views]
Main.storyboard - ViewController
↓ Push
Second.storyboard - SecondViewController
↓ Modal
Third.storyboard - ThirdViewController

I've been trying to back from ThirdViewController →　SecondViewController → ViewController

Back from ThirdViewController to SecondViewController is ok.

```swift
   // ThirdViewController
    @IBAction func tapBackBtn(_ sender: Any) {   
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        SecondViewController().back()
    }
```

However func back() - self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) doesn't work.

```swift
   // SecondViewController
    func back() {
    // Come here though...
     self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func tapBackBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        // It works though...
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Is there any way to back from Third/SecondViewController to ViewController automatically?
Thank you.

Comment: First question is : Why are you using different different storyboard for a single `ViewController`? If possible then add all ViewControllers in one storyboard only. It will provide easy navigation between controllers : `(1. Push to next, 2. Present controller from anywhere, 3. Back to one or back to more than one or back to root controller)`

Comment: Hi there, thank you all. 
Using different storyboards to plan out the project.

I finally figured out my problem using this code on SecondVC.
`override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            if type(of: presented) == ThirdViewController.self {
                self.back()
            }
        }
}`
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because by `SecondViewController().back()` you actually invoke an initializer of `SecondViewController` and create new instance of the view controller. This instance is different from which at navigation stack and you want to hide. So you invoke back function at instance which actually not at navigation stack and haven't a navigation controller.

To resolve the issue you can find a navigation controller at window hierarchy like this:

```
@IBAction func tapBackBtn(_ sender: Any) {   
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
         guard navigationControlller = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else { return }
         navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Or better solution is to rethink your app architecture and give navigation responsibility to some coordinating view controller. So coordinator will know when `ThirdViewController` should disappear and invoke `popViewController` at `NavigationController` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to return to **the first** view controller; aka **root**.

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Also you can pop back to a specific controller:

```
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(aController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Add this code to your backButton in the third view controller and it would take you to the first ViewController

Answer (score -1):

First at all you don't need to do `SecondViewController().back()` in you tapBackBtn method in ThirdViewController 'cuz this code don't do nothing.

Next, if you do `push` in your first ViewController there should be default `pop` implementation by tapping on back button in navigation controller.

Here is example of how to do your task simply:

// FirstViewController

```
@IBAction func showButtonDidPress(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Second", bundle: nil)
    let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
    navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

// SecondViewController

```
@IBAction func presentButtonDidPress(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Third", bundle: nil)
    let thirdViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController")
    present(thirdViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

// ThirdViewController

```
@IBAction func dismissButtonDidPress(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As you can see here I don't use any segue's and also use separated storyboards.

Additionally, you can use simple extension for UIStoryboard to make your code more beautiful:

```
extension UIStoryboard {
    static var main: UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    }

    static var second: UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Second", bundle: nil)
    }

    static var third: UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Third", bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

So to create new instance of ViewController you will do something like this:

```
let secondViewController = UIStoryboard.second.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
```